# How to change a file path in xcode 4?

Tags: xcode4

I have a project where a couple of files are in red, In XCode 3 I used to click the file Get Info and change the Path, but I have no idea how to do it in the new XCode 4.

Comment: Actually the easiest way is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16518071/184245

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on your file, and then open the right side pane (there is a button in the top right corner). There you will see Identity and Type. Under the location drop down there is a small icon of I'm not sure what. If you click it, it lets you choose a file. I think that is what you want.

Answer (score 7):

My method of choice is to just drag in the files from the new location and delete the references to the ones in the old location.

Comment: Yes, great idea! Just remember to drop it onto the project.