# xcode searches for prefix.pch file in wrong directory

Tags: ios7, xcode5, pch

i made a xcode project and changed the name of the folder in xcode as well as in finder. then i proceeded to relink them via the method shown here: [Renaming xcode 4 project and the actual folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262613/renaming-xcode-4-project-and-the-actual-folder)

so originally the folder was weatherScan2 which i renamed to weatherScan and xcode shows that there are no issues. However when i click build, there's a clang error that says:
 no such file or directory: '/Users/user/Documents/Xcode/WeatherScan/WeatherScan2(thisis the folder that i renamed to weatherScan)/WeatherScan-Prefix.pch

clearly it should be looking for the pch file in weatherscan as there is no longer any weatherscan2 folder in existence. How should i redirect this?

i already tried deleting the pch file from xcode and then readding it but the same thing happens. what part of xcode is trying to look for the pch file in the old place and not the new renamed folder? all the other files seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, i realized the issue was in the target/build setting section where it still shows my app looking for the info and pch files in weatherScan2 folder. i edit that and everything works.