# Parse symbols not uploading

Tags: parse-platform, debug-symbols

When I run the parse cli with the symbols option, I get the following message: The file “ParseSymbols” couldn’t be saved in the folder “tmp”.

It then says "Uploaded symbol files.", but when I look at my crash reports on the parse website, it says they are all unsymbolicated (iOS).

I tried running the parse cli with sudo, but it still got the same message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. Don't know what I am doing wrong either...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with Parse. I had to rename the main folder inside my project directory and remove the spaces, and after doing so it worked fine.

```
"ProjectFolder/Source File Folder" ->  "ProjectFolder/SourceFileFolder"
```

Renaming the folder is actually a bit painful. I had to refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262613/renaming-xcode-4-project-and-the-actual-folder).

Answer (score 0):

I added the -p flag and it worked (and my project file path has spaces in it).

```
parse symbols -p /path/to/project.xcarchive
Uploading iOS symbol files...
Fetching required resources...
Additional resources installed.
Uploaded symbol files.
```