# dyld issues library not loaded

Tags: ios, dyld

When I have tried to build my target I get this error with dynamic linker:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
```

I use this iphonesim library [link](https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim) that referenced on path as above.

I use Xcode 4.3 and in this case I think the path wrong.

How to change this path to correct path?

Comment: did you had the dylid to the target? 
see [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782224/how-to-change-a-file-path-in-xcode-4

Comment: thanks, but I think this problem due incorrect path for framework search path (for iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient framework). In XCode 4.2 everything work good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have download this library again and recompile it.

I think this is related due XCode 4.3 have another path for framework.

Please check this link [link](http://blog.justus-beyer.de/2012/02/after-xcode-update-to-4-3-xcodebuild-fails/)

Comment: how to download library again?

Comment: @klm123 have you followed the link in my answer?

Comment: yes, but I don't see donwload instructions.  Only "tell the system about the new path". In general I have similar problem with different library: @rpath/libCore.so .In wonder if I can apply your solution to my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455492/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libcore-so

Comment: @klm123 so I suppose you don't need to download nothing new. So there is just differences between paths, but you need to check. in my case the library was in another folder. so my answer does not solve any problems with paths, but it does in case with standard frameworks and different Xcode versions.

Comment: Thank you. How to check which folder libCore is? What is @rpath?

Comment: @kim123 I have answered on your question. So can you check where is the library is contained in previous version? I don't faced with this library.